# como fazer quanto clicar no titulo vai para uma pagina com o texto completo

Tags: php, html

eu estou fazendo blog usando html,css e php mas eu não sei como fazer para quando eu clicar no titulo da reportagem
ser direciona para uma pagina com o texto completo, igual os portais de noticias. que quando você clica no titulo da reportagem você vai para uma pagina com um link diferente e com o texto completo. qualquer duvida para responder a pergunta e só pergunta.

```
<section class="postagens">

    <?php 

        /*sistema de pesquisa no blog*/
        if(isset($_POST['procurar'])){
        
            $pesquisa = $_POST['titulos'];          

            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE titulo LIKE '%$pesquisa%'");

            $sql->execute(array($pesquisa));

            $info = $sql->fetchAll();
        }

    ?>

     <div class="container">
            <?php 
            
                /*pega todos as postagens no banco de dado*/
                foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
                    $titulos = $value['titulo'];
                    $resumo = $value['resumo'];
                    $imagem = $value['imagem']; 
            ?>
                    <div id="box">
                        <?php echo '<p> <img  src=" ' .$imagem. ' "></p> ' ?>
                        <?php echo "<h3>".$titulos."</h3>"?>
                        <?php echo '<p class="resumos">'.$resumo.'</p>' ?>
                    </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
     
</section>
```

Comment: então, você faz um select na reportagem, depois adiciona as informações na página.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite.

Isso é bem comum para sites de notícias, recomendo que passe o id da notícia por meio de um `GET` e crie uma página especifica para exibir uma notícia.

Nesse código que me parece ser sua home, seria somente necessário que envolva o seu titulo com um link (algo como `<a href='url_da_pagina?id=id_noticia'>`), mas vou adicionar algumas dicas para melhorar seu código.

**Em sua home page**

Começando pela sua pesquisa no banco de dados. Supondo que `$_POST['titulos']` seja um input de usuário, recomendo que use o `bindValue()` isso ajuda a prevenir injeções SQL, minha recomendação é **NUNCA COLOCAR INPUT DE USUÁRIO DIRETAMENTE NA SUA QUERY**.

```
<?php 
/*sistema de pesquisa no blog*/
   if(isset($_POST['procurar']))
   {
    $pesquisa = $_POST['titulos'];          
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE titulo LIKE '%$pesquisa%'");
    $sql->execute(array($pesquisa));
    $info = $sql->fetchAll();
  }       
?>
```

Recomendo que troque para isso:

```
<?php 
   /*sistema de pesquisa no blog*/
   if(isset($_POST['procurar']))
   {
      //$pesquisa = $_POST['titulos'];          
      $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE titulo LIKE :pesquisa");
      $sql->bindValue(':pesquisa', "%{$_POST['titulos']}%");
      $sql->execute();
      $info = $sql->fetchAll();
   }       
?>
```

Agora para fazer o link para a página:

```
<div class="container">
   <?php 
      /*pega todos as postagens no banco de dado*/
      foreach ($info as $key => $value)
      {
         /*$titulos = $value['titulo'];
         $resumo = $value['resumo'];
         $imagem = $value['imagem'];*/
         echo "<div id='box'>";
               echo "<p> <img  src='{$value['imagem']}'></p>";
               echo "<h3><a href='meu_link?id_noticia={$value['id_noticia']}'>{$value['titulo']}</a></h3>";
               echo "<p class='resumos'>{$value['resumo']}</p>";
         echo "</div>";
       }
    ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

A parte importante é cercar o seu titulo com uma tag `<a>`, onde está escrito '**meu_link**' é a url para a nova página de notícias e o `?id_noticia={$value['id_noticia']}` é para montar o GET, de resto eu só mudei a estrutura do código para ficar mais organizado (em minha opinião).

**Em sua página de notícias** (que vai ter que ser criada)

Agora para pegar essa notícia em especifico:

```
<?php 
       /*Buscar notícia em especifico */
       if(isset($_GET['id_noticia']))
       {      
          $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id_noticia = :id");
          $sql->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id_noticia']);
          $sql->execute();
          $ret = $sql->fetchAll();
       }
       else
       {
          //Se não tiver o $_GET['id_noticia']
       }       
 ?>
```

Depois é só montar o html com o resultado